# Setting up two way gmail authentication in Linux box

Tags: linux

I've successfully set up 2 way authentication on my android mobile using the Google authenticator Android App that I've downloaded from Play Store .

Now I want to set up a similar functionality on my Ubuntu Machine .

Can anyone help me in setting this up on my linux box ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First you have to install the proper PAM

  *sudo apt-get install libpam-google-authenticator*
- Next create a secret key for your user run

  *google-authenticator*
- Notice the secret key and your emergency keys
- Add the secret key to your google-authenticator app

To use PAM with sshd:

- Edit */etc/pam.d/sshd* and add

  *auth required pam_google_authenticator.so*
- Edit */etc/ssh/sshd_config*

  *ChallengeResponseAuthentication yes*
- Restart your sshd

Answer (score 0):

Google Authenticator uses OATH standard to generate OTPs. Try using OATH Toolkit oathtool.

http://www.nongnu.org/oath-toolkit/oathtool.1.html

After appropriate setup of secrets, it should work.